# Use SwiftData @Model and ObservableObject/@Published in the same class?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-data

```
import SwiftData

@Model
final class PracticeData: ObservableObject, Codable {
    var score: Int
    var results: [PracticeResult]
    @Published var latestResult: Bool? //Error Property wrapper cannot be applied to a computed property
    var trend: Float
```

Im new to swift so Im kinda stuck. I have a view that is in a sheet that adds a new result to results (and overrides latestResult). When I close the sheet, the variable is displayed in the underlying view but is not updated. I need to go back to another view and come back to see the change. How do I use published and @Model at the same time? And if not possible, how do I update the view after so that it is updated with the new value of latestResult?

EDIT:

```
import SwiftData

@Model
final class PracticeData: Codable {
    public var score: Int
    var results: [PracticeResult]
    var latestResult: Bool?
    var trend: Float
```

```
var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                ForEach(lesson.vocab) { vocab in
                    var practiceData: PracticeData = vocab.practiceData
                    var score: Int = practiceData.score
                    ...
                    Text(String(score))
                    Button("addToScore", action: {
                                score += 1
                    })
                }
```

Comment: A class declared with the `@Model` macro conforms to Observable so there is no need (maybe even an error) to conform it to ObservableObject. May I suggest watching [Discover Observation in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10149) and also [Meet SwiftData](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10187)

Comment: Model can’t invalidate Views you shouldn’t mix the old ObservableObject that relies on DynamicProperty with the new macros that have a completely new mechanism.

Comment: thanks for the videos. I updated the code based on the first video (8:12 in Discover Observation in SwiftUI), but it still doesn't update the score. I have to go out of the view and back in for the displayed score to be updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As other commenters said, `@Model` also makes your class `Observable`, just like `@Observable`. You should not use `ObservableObject` - your class is already `Observable`.

Your mistake in the last code snippet is how you update the score.

```
score += 1
```

is just updating the local `Int` variable `score`. That doesn't call the setter of `PracticeData.score` (in which there is some code related to observation, added by `@Model`), and so the views don't observe the change.

You should instead do:

```
practiceData.score += 1
```